# Errors CS0116 and CS0246

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm building a simple class that allows me to calculate the dimensions of the room for a class and I'm having trouble getting the code to work. When I run it these are the errors I am receiving.

/p1/room.cs(1,7): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

/p1/room.cs(48,19): warning CS0108: 'Room.GetType()' hides inherited member 'object.GetType()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

/p1/room.cs(1,1): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Using' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I did some research and found that it seems that most of the time the two above errors refer to either unmatched brackets, but after searching through my room.cs file, I was unable to find any. In comparing the headers to my files to other classes I've found I can't find any differences.

Here is my room.cs file

```
Using System;

namespace p1
{
    public class Room
    {
       private string type;
       private double length;
       private double width;
       private double height;

       public Room()
       {
            type = "Default";
            length = 0.0;
            width = 0.0;
            height = 0.0;
       }

       public Room(string t, double l, double w, double h)
       {
            type = t;
            length = l;
            width = w;
            height = h;
       }


       public void SetType(string t)
       {
            type = t;
       }

       public void SetLength(double l)
       {
            length = l;
       }
       public void SetWidth(double w)
       {
            width = w;
       }
       public void SetHeight(double h)
       {
            height = h;
       }
       public string GetType()
       {
            return type;
       }
       public double GetLength()
       {
            return length;
       }
       public double GetWidth()
       {
            return width;
       }
       public double GetHeight()
       {
            return height;
       }


       public double GetArea()
       {
            return length*width;
       }
       public double GetVolume()
       {
            return length*width*height;
       }
       public void Display()
       {
            Console.WriteLine("Room Type: " + this.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("Room Length: " + this.GetLength());
            Console.WriteLine("Room Width: " + this.GetWidth());
            Console.WriteLine("Room Height: " + this.GetHeight());
            Console.WriteLine("Room Area: " + this.GetArea().ToString("F 2") + " sq ft " );
            Console.WriteLine("Room Volume: " + this.GetVolume().ToString("F 2") + " cu ft ");
       }
   }
}
```

I can also post the program.cs file if needed, but this was getting quite long and I didn't want it to be unreadable.

Comment: Change `Using` to `using` and see if that doesn't fix the rest of the errors.

Comment: I would also change all of the GetXXX/SetXXX method pairs to properties so it looks more like C# than Java, and it gets rid of the warning on `GetType`.

Comment: `GetType` is already defined in Object. Every class inherits from Object in `C#`. You either need to `override` it, or think about a better name.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt It's not `virtual` so you can't override it.  I don't think hiding it is a problem here since the usages are very different, but using properties instead would remove the error and be cleaner.

Comment: Making the u in using lowercase fixed the two errors. I went the simple route and just changed GetType to something else and everything went better. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax to use NameSpace should be using not Using

Replace `Using System;` with `using System;`

Use

```
public new string GetType()
{
    return type;
}
```

in place of to get rid of warning "Use new keyword is hiding was intented"

```
public string GetType()
{
    return type;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be better if you offered a brief explanation.

Comment: If that's the only problem then the question should be closed as a typo.

Comment: It's not only a typo, it also explains the warning about hidding base functions. But yeah, the answer should be a bit more explained to be good.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what vivek nuna already said, you should get used to C#'s concept of properties. This will make your code less verbose and avoids the specific problem of hiding `GetType()`:

```
public class Room
{
   public string Type { get; set; } = "Default"; // with C#6 property initialization
   public double Length { get; set; }
   public double Width { get; set; }
   public double Height { get; set; }

   public Room() {} // no code here, Type is initalized, double is 0 by default

   public Room(string t, double l, double w, double h)
   {
        Type = t;
        Length = l;
        Width = w;
        Height = h;
   }

   public double GetArea()
   {
        return Length * Width;
   }
   public double GetVolume()
   {
        return Length * Width * Height;
   }
   public void Display()
   {
        Console.WriteLine("Room Type: " + Type);
        Console.WriteLine("Room Length: " + Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Room Width: " + Width);
        Console.WriteLine("Room Height: " + Height);
        Console.WriteLine("Room Area: " + GetArea().ToString("F 2") + " sq ft " );
        Console.WriteLine("Room Volume: " + GetVolume().ToString("F 2") + " cu ft ");
    }
}
```

From outside you can now simply access the properties:

```
Room r = new Room();
r.Height = 12;
Console.WriteLine(r.Height);
```

The compiler does all the work you did yourself in your code. It creates backing fields for each property and the getter and setter methods. You don't have to do this and can concentrate on the real work.

Comment: Even better, he can do `Room r = new Room{ Height = 12 };`